# remove dropdown node on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this dropdown and I would like to remove all of it's children when the page loads. Here is my code.

```html
<select id="mylist">
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
    <option value="F">F</option>
    <option value="R">R</option>
</select>`
```

Comment: any attempt ???

Comment: this is my js code but don't work

Comment: window.onload=function() {

          var select=document.getElementById("warehouse");
          for (i=0;select.length;i++)
          {
              select.remove(i);
          }

        }

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you want to remove all options?

Comment: yes I want remove all options

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I use the detach()

```js
$(window).on('load',function(){
  $('#mylist>option').detach();
});
```

Jquery method to keep the values for the case that you want to re-append the list without loosingany events or data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `empty()` to remove all the child, so if you want to do it when the page is loaded you have to do:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#mylist").empty();
});
```

With this option you will remove the child and all kind of data stored inside those nodes. Documentation: [jQuery empty documentation](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

If you want to keep data you can use `.detach()`, [jQuery detach documentation](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)

Answer (score 0):

Why is everyone suggesting the use of jQuery? He's clearly a beginner.

I would use the document API for this, you don't need a whole library for one function.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
   for(var i = 0; i<document.getElementsByTagName("select"); i++){
     var b = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[i];
     b.parentElement.removeChild(b);
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set select html to blank.

```js
$('#mylist').html('');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  id="mylist">
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
    <option value="F">F</option>
    <option value="R">R</option>
</select>
```